# Get a date from HTML date form and insert it into a PostgreSQL table using PHP

Tags: php, forms, postgresql, date, sql-insert

I've got a HTML form with a Date

```
<input type="date" name="mydate">
```

This is how it look like: [image: date form]

My PHP script starts when the form is submitted. It look like this more or less:

```
$mydate = $_POST['mydate'];
$query = "insert into datetable(when) values({$mydate})";
$res = pg_query($db, $query);
```

It just doesn't work. When I try to manually run the generate query in my psql CLI I get an error like this:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "when" is of type date but expression is of type integer 
> LINE 1: ..., when) values (1990-01-01...
>                            ^ 
> HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
> ```

However I've got no idea how I can do it.

I've tried to convert `mydate` using `date()` and `timetostr` in PHP. I've tried to do something with [`to_char()`, `to_date()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html) as well. However I still cannot do anything to make it run...

Comment: You should read about SQL injection.

Comment: Use `pg_query_params` or add apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the date as string. Few examples.

```
$mydate = pg_escape_literal($_POST['mydate']);
/*        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ */
$query = "insert into datetable(when) values({$mydate})";
$res = pg_query($db, $query);


$mydate = pg_escape_string($_POST['mydate']);
/*        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   v         v */
$query = "insert into datetable(when) values('{$mydate}')";
$res = pg_query($db, $query);


$mydate = $_POST['mydate'];
$query = "insert into datetable(when) values($1)";
/*     vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv              vvvvvvvvv^^ */
$res = pg_query_params($db, $query, [$mydate]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-string.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php